# Snakes, snakes, snakes!

Tags: riddle

> I am a long snake, terrible to everyone,
> I unite everything that has fallen apart.
> I am hard to conquer for human, even the smartest ones,
> I may help you to find your size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> An integral.

I am a long snake, terrible to everyone,

> The integral sign (∫) looks like an elongated s, or a snake. Integrals can also be quite difficult to calculate, making some people fear them.

I unite everything that has fallen apart.

> A derivate measures the sensitivity to change in a point in a function. An integral takes a derivate and unites all the points into the original function again.

I am hard to conquer for human, even the smartest ones,

> Calculating integrals is taught as higher education. Even then, learning to use it correctly is often a lot of work.

And it helps to find the size.

> Integrals are often used to calculate areas and volumes.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> a measuring tape?!

It's almost terrible to everyone since

> it either tells you that you are shorter / fatter / slimmer than an average person.

It's hard to conquer

> [get yourself slim / fat / tall] to the extent that everybody likes it.

And it helps to find the size.